# Which format for the bad pixel image (Dicom Tag 0014,3080) file format

Tags: dicom, image-formats

I wrote a Dicom/DICONDE file library. Now I would like to add a bad pixel image into the file.

According to Dicom standard part06, the bad pixel image is to be stored in tag 0014,3080 with data type OB. But what is the exact format? I guess it is one bit per pixel, 0 means pixel OK, 1 means bad pixel.

Can someone confirm that?
Where can I find some sample Dicom files containing a bad pixel?

EDIT: ASTM E 2339-15 do not specify the bad pixel image format.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad pixel image format is described in ASTM E 2767-11 document in table 5. This is exactly as I expected: Byte image with the same number of rows and columns as the Pixel Data (7FE0,0010). The pixel data of this image will contain a "1" for a good pixel and a "0" for a bad pixel.

Answer (score 1):

This tag belongs to the DICONDE standard, a standard which is used in industry for imaging related to non-desctructive testing. It is not included in any of the DICOM IODs for medical imaging (see part 3 - you will not find any reference to this attribute).

I suspect you want to use your DICO*M* library for medical imaging - in this application domain, this attribute is not used.

If you really want to support DICONDE, the [DICONDE standard](https://www.astm.org/Standards/E2339.htm) should tell about the syntax and semantics. I would have had a look, but unlike DICOM it is not available for free.

Comment: It is for DICONDE application (NDT radiology). DICONDE is DICOM with an adapted data dictionary.

Comment: I bought the ASTM E 2339 document. Unfortunately, there is no mention about bad pixel map nor tag 0014,3080. Could you please point me to the correct paragraph?

Comment: That's bad. Unfortunately, I do not have a copy of the standard and do not intend to purchase one. I know about DICOM but not about DICONDE.